# Finding attributes of mounted SD card

Tags: linux, arch-linux, sd-card

My SD card is automounted fine as /dev/sdb:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sda      8:0    0    80G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    78G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
sr1     11:1    1  1024M  0 rom  
sdb      8:16   1   7.4G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1    56M  0 part /media/boot
└─sdb2   8:18   1   2.7G  0 part /media/af599925-1134-4b6e-8883-fb6a99cd58f1
```

In `dmesg`:

```
[ 1206.970596] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I would like to know a few attributes - serial #, manufacturer id, etc. that I thought would be in `/sys/class`. I have searched `/sys/class/scsi_disk/3:0:0:0/` without any luck.

Where would I find this information? I am using the latest version of Arch-linux.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The proper way to do this, in Arch Linux but by now in all systems which use *udev*, is the command:

```
  sudo udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb
```

in your case.

Edit:

A reply to your comment: I believe you are mistaken. The *class* is a view of a device which is independent of the low-level implementation details. The classic example is a disk. You may of course have a SCSI disk or an ATA disk, but, at the *class* level, they are the same thing. The idea of the *class* is to allow users to build userspace code which is independent of how they are connected to the network, how they work, which device driver they use, and so on. In a way, the *class* is the highest level of abstraction available as a model for devices.

Thus you are wrong in searching for such details as your SD card vendor (which, by the way, should be in */sys/class/mmc_host*, if anything at all) within */sys/class*.

Comment: Ok, this gives all that information. But - I though `/sys/class` was supposed to be a way do navigate `/dev` without all the device-specific (set by `udev`) hieracrchy? Am I wrong about that?

Comment: @CharlesPehlianian See the Edit to my answer

Comment: Ok - I was under the wrong impression then. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesPehlivanian: You can get to that detailed information via `/sys/class`; see @Robert's answer. It may just not be the best way. However, on some systems (e.g. Android), `udevadm` isn't available.

Answer (score 7):

The exact layout is driver dependent, but try searching `/sys` for some MMC (SD) specific keywords. Below is from an ARM-based embedded system:

```
$ find /sys -name "oemid"
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/oemid
$ find /sys -name "cid"
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/cid
$ find /sys -name "csd"
/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:aaaa/csd
```

[Bunnie's blog entry on SD card shenanigans](http://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?page_id=1022) is a good place to start back-tracking what those ID numbers mean.

Comment: Great. 
In my case, with this answer, I could find most SD and MMC device attributes. cid, csd, scr, date, fwrev, hwrev, manfid, name, oemid, serial...

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Arch Linux, but "usb-devices" lists the details of all USB devices the system knows about, and included the following for a USB key I plugged in:

```
T:  Bus=03 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=02 Cnt=02 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0781 ProdID=5567 Rev=01.26
S:  Manufacturer=SanDisk
S:  Product=Cruzer Blade
S:  SerialNumber=4C532000060624123092
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=200mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me what I was asking for, but I'd like to understand `/sys/class` a little better so I'd like an answer based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at /sys/class/scsi_disk I discovered that (on my system) that these are symkinks to actual disks.   Indeed when I do an "ls -la /sys/class/scsi_disk/ it shows a symlink for 8:0:0:0 to ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.3/3-2.3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/scsi_disk/8:0:0:0

If I then shift in to :/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb3/3-2/3-2.3/3-2.3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0  It has a number of files which I suspect are of interest to you including -

```
model = model of the drive
vendor = the drive vendor
```

Also of interest might be parsing /proc/scsi -

```
/proc/scsi/scsi          contains the description of each device and associated host
                         as scsi8 which lets me derive the "8" in the next bit.

/proc/scsi/usb-storage/8 contains the Vendor, Product and serial number
```

Comment: When do `ls` on your `/sys/devices/...` directory, as you indicate, I get a symlink back to `/sys/class/scsi_disk/8:0:0:0`, which is where my question began. I don't see any files for model, vendor, only `FUA, device, allow_restart`, etc. I have searched these with no luck.